# Visual Studio 2019 C++ After Successed Build Run an .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, build-events

How to make my Visual Studio 2019, running an custom exe after my C++ Build successfully compile?

i tried to insert into the PostEvent builds, following command: "start C:\Test.exe" but the executable starts while the compile is running ( compile completes only when i exit the Test.exe).

I wanted to start the Program directly after the compiler succesfully builds.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: i dont wanted to debug. i simply want to start an .exe after compiler successes. ( not the one i builded so far)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty but it does the job: `powershell "Start-Process c:\test.exe"`